# Allow ComboBox items to be viewed but not selected

Tags: c#, xaml

I select the displayed item of a ComboBox in the code behind.

I’d like the user to view the list of items that can be selected by the code behind but not to be able to change the preselected item by selecting another item from the list presented on the GUI.

Is there a WPF/XAML setting for ComboBox that enables the user to view a ComboBox’s list of selectable items but not select an item from the list?

I’ve tried IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="False" and IsEnabled="False" but they don’t give me what I want.

Comment: Thanks Markus.  I looked at that before I posted my question but I couldn't see a solution in there for my problem.

Comment: I solved the problem by using the ComboBox SelectionChanged event to recalculate the SelectedValue in the code behind whenever the user selects a new item from the ComboBox list of selectable items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
in xaml, add three event handlers

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ListCollection}" 
          PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown" 
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ComboBox_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="ComboBox_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"/>
```

code-behind

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        e.Handled = true;
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}

private void ComboBox_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
}

private void ComboBox_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Svetlana.  I can get away with using the ComboBox SelectionChanged event.